# Online webRTC audio stream server configuration

Tags: node.js, firebase, webrtc

I'd like to build a simple online webRTC application where:

- User A connects to the webpage, grants access to his microphone and starts streaming
- User B connects to another tab, collects the audio stream and is able to hear it.

This, as I've been studying for a couple of days, should be fairly simple, but I'm having severe problems with actually sending and recieving the streams. In particular, I've been following [this](https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC) guide which uses firestore to store and retrieve offers, but it is all very confusing, and aimed to 2 very different, changing devices which need to call each other. 
My question is, with my first device being fixed, what are the steps I should take from the recieving end, (user B) to actually connect to the webpage and starting hearing the audio? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good implemented solution using [MultiRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiRTC)